# How to await Task completion and return a variable?

Tags: android, kotlin, async-await, kotlin-coroutines

I am stuck on an attempt to write "idiomatic" Kotlin async code. I am trying to refactor a barcode scanner as a top/ package level function.

How could I make the thread wait for the `scanner.process(image)` to complete, and return the list of barcodes before continuing?

The code partially shows my "closest" attempt to solve the problem.

```
package com.example.demo

import android.util.Log
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.Barcode
import com.google.mlkit.vision.barcode.BarcodeScanning
import com.google.mlkit.vision.common.InputImage
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

class BarcodeActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val scanButton = findViewById<Button>(...)
        scanButton.setOnClickListener {
          // Get Bitmap image
            runBarcode(image)
        }
    }

  // Member function, calling codes should return a list of barcodes
  // after completing 
  fun runBarcode(image: InputImage) =  runBlocking {
    Log.d("BAR", "One")
    val codes = async { scanBarcodes(image)}
    Log.d("BAR", "Three")
  }
}

// Package level function
suspend fun scanBarcodes(image: InputImage) = coroutineScope {
    val scanner = BarcodeScanning.getClient()
    val codes = async {
        scanner.process(image)
            .addOnSuccessListener { barcodes ->
                val barcodeList = mutableListOf<Barcode>()
                Log.d("BAR", "Two")
                for (barcode in barcodes) {
                    barcodeList.add(barcode)
                }
                return@addOnSuccessListener
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.e("BAR", "Barcode scan failed")
            }
    }
    codes.await()
}
```

prints

```
D/BAR One
D/BAR Three
D/BAR Two
```

and the inferred return type of `scanBarcodes` is `Task<MutableListOf<Barcode>>`

In Dart/ Flutter I would write something like `<T> scanBarcodes() async {}` and accordingly `var codes = await ...` to solve the problem. I suppose I could use `val codes = runBlocking{...}` to block the main thread while completing. However, this async pattern is apparently [strongly discouraged](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/composing-suspending-functions.html#async-style-functions) in Kotlin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Don't use `runBlocking` for this. It will block your main thread, which freezes up the UI (user cannot scroll, click or even navigate away from your app) while it's waiting. It also puts you at risk of an ANR crash. You should launch a coroutine from your click listener so you can make this function a suspend function.
2. To use a callback as a suspend function, often you have to convert it into something that suspends by using `suspendCancellableCoroutine()`. However, the Kotlin coroutines library already provides this for you in this case with the `Task.await()` suspend function. If it is not available to import in your project, add this dependency to your build.gradle:

```groovy
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.6.0"
```

The `await()` function returns the result of the task, or it throws an exception if the task fails, so you should wrap it in try/catch instead of using success and failure listeners.

Here's how to fix your code:

```
class BarcodeActivity() {

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val scanButton = findViewById<Button>(...)
        scanButton.setOnClickListener {
            lifecycleScope.launch { 
                val barcodes = scanBarcodes(image)
                // do something with returned barcodes or maybe show message if list empty
            }
        }
    }

}

// Package level function
suspend fun scanBarcodes(image: InputImage): List<Barcode> {
    return try {
        BarcodeScanning.getClient()
            .process(image)
            .await()
    } catch(e: Exception) {
        Log.e("BAR", "Barcode scan failed")
        emptyList() // Returns an empty list on failure, but you might want to handle it differently, like returning null.
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this fixed my problem. I did not understand either `lifecycleScope` or `Tasks.await()` beforehand. Thanks a lot!

Also interesting that you warn about the use of `runBlocking` when the Kotlin coroutine docs seem to make good use of them.

Comment: Is there a caveat regarding adding dependencies to `play-services` BTW?

Comment: The docs use runBlocking in its (almost) only appropriate place: directly in the `main` function of a JVM application. It’s at the top level main function so it keeps the application from terminating until all the coroutines are finished. Otherwise `main` would return while coroutines are still running and terminate the app. This is not relevant to Android. No caveats I can think of.

Comment: You can use `runBlocking` on Android inside functions that you know will never be called on the main thread. It’s just unusual to ever need to do this. If you’re already using coroutines in you app, it’s unwieldy to try to separately use multi-threading. You might want to for ease of use for Java portions of your code, but then it’s easier on both ends to expose Java Completables than to expose blocking functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the fun `runBarcode()` as below.

```
fun runBarcode(image: InputImage) {
    lifecycle.coroutineScope.launch {
        Log.d("BAR", "One")
        val codes = async { scanBarcodes(image)}
        codes.await()
        Log.d("BAR", "Three")
    }
}
```

await() is the suspendable function this will return DeferedJob object, which has the result value which returns from suspendable function (DefferedJob()) if any. This will help you to print

```
D/BAR One
D/BAR Two
D/BAR Three
```

Hope this is what you are expecting ..

Comment: This will block the main thread, freezing user input and risk an ANR crash.

Comment: Yeah, runBlocking will block the main thread, I am rewriting that. But, still the problem is scanBarcodes() has listener, how that will till return from the call back listner

Comment: Need to use suspendCancellableCoroutine to convert a callback into a suspend function.

Comment: Thanks @Navaspk, I tried implementing your suggestion. The program still does not wait until `scanner.process(image)` is completed. Perhaps I should refactor that Task call?

Comment: This is still wrong. There's no reason to call `async` and immediately call `await()` on the result. The compiler even issues you a warning if you do this because it's pointless. As you identified, the problem is in the other function that is not returning the result of the Task.